# How the show only 50% of the content box?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm creating a count down and i basically have tow divs inside a div

```html
<div>
   <div :class="`up up-${i - 1} gradient-white-gray`">{{ 200 - i }}</div>
   <div :class="`down down-${i - 1}`">{{ 200 - i }}</div>
</div>
```

for the down div i set `line-height: 0;` and so only 50% of the text is visible
but how can do the same thing for the up div

basically i want that every div shows only 50% of the content so that together can look like a real text

[image]

Comment: why not using one content and a linear-gradient as background?

Comment: @TemaniAfif actually i didn't try but i don't know if it will allow me to have this animation of a countdown